# how to secure api keys in the front-end / client side Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, environment-variables

***Scenarios where i require to keep the keys as a secret***

1. Azure / Google Maps API KEYs
2. STUN & TURN Server credentials for WEBRTC

First I was adding the keys directly , then I found out that those are very high vulnerabilities that others could take those credentials and use it for their needs

Later i tried using environment variables in `.env` file

But i could not find a way to use it properly

*(express + nodeJS)*

```
res.render("pages/crimestats", { apikey: process.env.AZURE_KEY })
```

here i was passing to the rendering page as a variable , but the key was still visible when i tried to see the source code on the browser.

So what is the proper way to use it ?

*What i have in my mind*

```
using an api call to get the key in the frontend 
//but then any one can call that api request in the browser console right?
```

Comment: The only way to protect an API key is to keep the key only on the server.  The client asks your server for some data and your server uses the API key to get the data from the API source and returns it back to the client.  Anything you send to the client will be visible to any hacker.

Comment: @jfriend00 i don't think we can load the map  in the server itself

Comment: Well, if you have to use the APIkey in the client, then you can't protect it.  It will be embedded somewhere in your page's Javsacript where hackers can see it.  Not much else to say.

Comment: @jfriend00 can i secure it using a  fetch api call in the javascript to get the keys  ? only doubt i have is , if i do the fetch request using the code , then they can see my fetch code and they reexecute in the broswer console .

Comment: FWIW, if I recall correctly the Google API returns the API key in the response, so unless you use both make the request from the server _and_ scrub the result before passing it back to the browser, it will be exposed.  I always assumed that Google allowed you to specify a list of domains from which it would accept requests for a given API key, but perhaps not.  I could 100% be misremembering all of this.

Comment: @SandrinJoy - There's no real point to getting the key with a fetch call.  Any hacker can see that too.  In fact, that makes it even easier for a hacker to fetch your key at any time without even having to parse it out of your web page.